# Has anyone managed to virtualize Windows 7 on a physical disk?

Tags: windows, ubuntu, virtualbox, virtualization, vmware-player

I have Windows 7 installed on a partition and running fine, but I want to access the parition from my Ubuntu installation with VirtualBox. I have created the virtual disk file and everything, but Windows gives me a Blue Screen of Death (BSOD) after a bit of loading with `error 0000007B` (it can't find the disk or something).

Has anyone managed to solve this problem?

Comment: You want access to your Windows 7 partition from your virutalized Ubuntu installation?

Comment: No, I want to start my physical Windows partition from my physical Ubuntu installation with VirtualBox.

Comment: Was there ever a solution found for this?

Answer (score 4):

I have managed to get Windows to boot. Basically, what happens is that all disk drivers (except the one you actually need) are disabled when booting, so when you get Windows in a VM it is unable to read its own disk. To fix this, just follow the advice in this KB article:

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/922976

Change two registry entries, and it will boot fine.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using a more complex method than the standard VirtualBox IDE/SATA/SCSI/whatever drivers, you may need to install the VirtualBox disk drivers that it uses for passthrough into the Windows 7 installation before it can boot. Missing drivers are listed as a reason for this error in [the knowledgebase](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/324103).

Comment: I tried that, still bluescreens :/